# Deprecationmessage getting content object in controller

Tags: typo3-9.x

i'm using following code to get the `uid` of a content object in my controller:

```
$this->configurationManager->getContentObject()->data['uid']
```

In `TYPO3 9.5` backend at `Upgrade -> Scan Extension Files` there is a notice, that this function is deprecated. Until now i couldn't find an alternative to get the `uid`.

I'm not sure if i understand the message correctly, will this function still work in `TYPO3 10`?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to worry about this deprecation message. In the migration notes you can see that the warning is about `getContentObject` in `AbstractContentObject`, and it tells you to rename `getContentObject()` to `getContentObjectRenderer()`.

However, yours is not for an `AbstractContentObject` class, it detects it on a `ConfigurationManagerInterface` class, which has a `getContentObject` but no `getContentObjectRenderer`.

So you can safely ignore the message. As the Scan Extension Files window says at the top: "false positives/negatives are impossible to avoid".